# Display PDF file stored in S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3

Im using multer-s3 to upload a PDF to S3 bucket, and it works, but now I need to display the PDF without downloading it (just like [this](http://idtc-icai.s3.amazonaws.com/download/3.%20Collated%20Suggestions%20submitted%20on%20Draft%20Rules.pdf)) and I already tryied to use iframe, embed and object, each one with the src='link_to_s3_file' and when I access the page it just download the file.
That's my code to configure the upload:

```
const multer = require('multer')
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3')
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION
})
const s3 = new AWS.S3()

const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET,
        acl: 'private',
        contentDisposition: 'attachment',
        contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
        metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
        },
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.originalname)
        }
    })
})
```

How can I display the PDF instead of download it?

Comment: `Content-Disposition: Attachment` means content should be [downloaded and saved locally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition), use `inline`

Answer (score 0):

In order to open PDF directly, without downloading it, you should change 2 things:

```
ContentDisposition='inline'
ContentType='application/pdf'
```

If you're sure that `multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE` will recognize it correctly, you might not have to change this, but ContentDisposition is for sure one thing you have to change. `attachment` means that it will download it and `inline` is to open it in browser directly.